# what does `l` in `lseek` of unistd.h mean?

Tags: c, unix, lseek

I am reading APUE to explore the details of C and Unix, and encounter  `lseek`

```
NAME
lseek - move the read/write file offset
SYNOPSIS
#include <unistd.h>

off_t lseek(int fildes, off_t offset, int whence);
```

What does l mean, is it length?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244525/why-is-the-function-called-lseek-not-seek

Comment: `l` is for long, as @bolov suggests. However, I cannot mark that as a duplicate, since it's on another stack exchange site. Posting an answer with the same content doesn't feel right also.. Hmm..

Comment: I feel sort of know nothing about C when start to read APUE.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=6): The character l in the name lseek means "long integer."

Comment: @gsamaras: I agree. But posting the same answer and linking to the original answer on Software Engineering might still be appropriate.

Comment: @gsamaras I however feel perfectly ok with reposting other answers ;p

Comment: The question isn't necessarily off-topic here just because it is on-topic elsewhere. I see nothing wrong with asking these kind of questions.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen you are right, I checked on [meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/275467), and they say exactly this, so I went ahead and posted an answer! Swordfish, nice timing, but I posted an answer already. :) Lunding, of course it's not off-topic, I just didn't know what to do with cross-site duplicates. Now that I read the meta post, I know! :)

Comment: @gsamaras What now? call you slowfox?

Answer (score 6):

`l` is for **long** integer.

It is named like that to *differentiate* from the old `seek()` in version 2 of AT&T Unix. This is an anachronism before the off_t type was introduced.

---

References:

[Infohost](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=6) indicates:

> The character `l` in the name `lseek` means "long integer". Before the
>   introduction of the `off_t` data type, the offset argument and the
>   return value were long integers. `lseek` was introduced with Version 7
>   when long integers were added to C. (Similar functionality was
>   provided in Version 6 by the functions `seek` and `tell`.)

As noted at the foot of [lseek.html](https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/lseek.2.html):

> ```
>  A seek() function appeared in Version 2 AT&T UNIX, later renamed into
>  lseek() for ``long seek'' due to a larger offset argument type.
> ```

---

Note: Paraphrased from [Why is the function called lseek(), not seek()?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244525/why-is-the-function-called-lseek-not-seek)